# Question about the dilation properties of lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis

The Lebesgue integral has such property:
$$\delta^d\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(\delta x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$$
Then what if integral is on $E$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^d$, do we still have
 $$\delta^d\int_{E}f(\delta x)dx=\int_{E}f(x)dx$$
or we need to make some modifications?

Comment: You have $$\delta^d \int_E f(\delta x)\,dx = \int_{\delta\cdot E} f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: What does $E$ stand for? a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Answer (score 2):

Introduce $\chi_E$, the characteristic function of $E$. Then 
$$\int_E f(x)\,dx = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \chi_E(x) f(x)\,dx$$
Apply the dilation formula to the integral on the right:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} \chi_E(x) f(x)\,dx
=\delta^d \int_{\mathbb R^d} \chi_E(\delta x) f(\delta x)\,dx
$$
What is $\chi_E(\delta x)$? It is a function that is equal to $1$ only when $\delta x\in E$. In other words, when $x\in \delta^{-1}E$ where $\delta^{-1}E = \{\delta^{-1}y: y\in E\}$. Hence, 
$$\delta^d \int_{\mathbb R^d} \chi_E(\delta x) f(\delta x)\,dx
= \delta^d \int_{\mathbb R^d} \chi_{\delta^{-1} E} (x) f(\delta x)\,dx
$$
Put everything together: 
$$\int_E f(x)\,dx =  \delta^d \int_{\delta^{-1} E}   f(\delta x)\,dx$$

Or, if you want to have $E$ on the right, 
$$\int_{\delta E} f(x)\,dx =  \delta^d \int_{ E}   f(\delta x)\,dx$$